# Fetch data from 3 models with foreign values and display using Django

Tags: mysql, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I use 3 tables where 2 table is master table and 1 table is reference table. And want to show data in index.html using django template.
How to show data in djano template?

I can fetch desired data from query but I want to convert this query to ORM and want to display data in DTL

BroadcastList

| ID (pk) | brl_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 |
| 2 | Test 2 |

Contact

| ID(pk) | f_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Rahul |
| 2 | Tina |
| 3 | Priti |

Broadcast_Contact

| ID | BroadcastID(fk) | ContactID(fk) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |

I want to display data broadcastlist wise in Django template

I want output like

| ID | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Priti |
| 2 | Tina |
| 2 | Rahul |

Query :- SELECT ab.id,ab.brl_name FROM Contact c JOIN Broadcast_Contact b ON c.ID=b.contactID JOIN BroadcastList ab ON ab.ID = b.broadcastID WHERE b.broadcastID = 2;

How to convert this query into ORM.I am new to django so need to understand how I achieve this.
I want to fetch data through ORM Queryset and display data in html page

models.py

```
class BroadcastList(models.Model):                        
    brl_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

class Contact(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

class Broadcast_Contact(models.Model):
    broadcast = models.ForeignKey(BroadcastList,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null
```

Comment: Can you include your models?

Comment: Yes, sure,


You can see now

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to your SQL query using Django's ORM would be:

```
qs = Contact.objects.filter(broadcast_contact_set__broadcast_id=2)
```

Since your models represent a many-to-many relation you could improve your models with adding a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField):

```
class BroadcastList(models.Model):                        
    brl_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

class Contact(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    broadcasts = models.ManyToManyField(BroadcastList, through="Broadcast_Contact")

class Broadcast_Contact(models.Model):
    broadcast = models.ForeignKey(BroadcastList,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null)
```

Note that if you don't want to reuse an existing table for the intermediary model `Broadcast_Contact` you don't need to specify it and can omit the [`through` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

With the `ManyToManyField` you can even do easier [related lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships):

```
qs = Contact.objects.filter(broadcasts__id=2)
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, will try this and update as soon as I tried it.